Change Users table with sanctum
Does Any one has and idea how to use applicants table (for example) instead of users table with laravel sanctum?
I tried adding this to auth.php but it didn't work
   'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'sanctum',
            'provider' => 'applicants',
        ],
    ],


'providers' => [
       'users' => [
           'driver' => 'eloquent',
           'model' => env('AUTH_MODEL', App\Models\User::class),
       ],

       'applicants' => [
           'driver' => 'eloquent',
           'model' => env('AUTH_MODEL', App\Models\API\Applicant::class),
       ],
   ],


Which version of laravel you are using? What did not work in you case after this configuration?please specify.

I am using laravel 11 , what happens is that when i try to use Auth::attempt() , i searches for user in users table not applicants table

Okay you want to search user from applicants table.Right?

yes ,I want to authenticate them from applicants  I am using this in login function :
   if (Auth::attempt(['mobile' => $data['mobile'], 'password' => $data['password']])) {
            $applicant = Auth::user();
            $data['token'] = $applicant->createToken('API Token')->plainTextToken; 
}else {


Okay,I have posted my answer.Please chcek and let me know if it works.Thanks

You can't use env('AUTH_MODEL'.. for two different model class.
Instead of your code try this one for applicants providers.
'providers' => [
       'users' => [
           'driver' => 'eloquent',
           'model' => env('AUTH_MODEL', App\Models\User::class),
       ],

       'applicants' => [
           'driver' => 'eloquent',
           'model' => App\Models\API\Applicant::class,
       ],
   ],

And in your guards add the providers name applicants not applicant.
In laravel 11 default guard is users.So in case of custom-guard(in your case api which point to applicants providers) do this to authenticate users.
if (Auth::guard('api')->attempt(['mobile' => $data['mobile'], 'password' => $data['password']])) 
{ 
  $applicant = Auth::guard('api')->user(); 
  $data['token'] = $applicant->createToken('API Token')->plainTextToken; 
}
else 
{
....
}

Try this,it will work.
In case of any other issue related to sanctum authentication You can take guide from this link.
https://github.com/savanihd/Laravel-11-REST-API-using-Sanctum/blob/main/config/auth.php
For more information about custom-guard configuration and how it will be accessed You can visit the official docs link given below..
https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/authentication#accessing-specific-guard-instances

Thank you for your answer and time , but I am getting this error now :
BadMethodCallException: Method Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard::attempt does not exist

  'guards' => [         'web' => [             'driver' => 'session',             'provider' => 'users',         ],         'api' => [             'driver' => 'session',             'provider' => 'applicants',         ],     ],  well here I changed api driver from sanctum to session and it now works fine , but is this the right thing to do ??

@AbdelfattahOmar, Yes 100% it is as per documentation. I am editing my answer and providing the offical doc link where you can explore more.Please upvote and accept my answer.Thanks

well there is something about needing 15 reputations to upvote but really thank you, I appreciate your help so much

To upvote you need 15 reputation but to accept answer I don't think there is any such limitation. BTW no issue thank you.

You can check the shared github link in my answer to know in details about sanctum authentication.
